# how to unregister achievements that don't have an associated URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, achievements

I am seeing some incomplete entries in our app's registered achievements.

Querying the achievements using the following graph api call

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/<appid>/achievements?access_token=<app_access_token>"
```

The call returns results like this:

```
{
"data": [{
    "id": "10150249221973207",
    "updated_time": "2011-09-08T07:42:46+0000",
    "context": {
        "display_order": 0
    }
}, {
    "id": "10150283711123407",
    "updated_time": "2011-07-22T11:54:35+0000",
    "context": {
        "display_order": 0
    }
}, {
    "url": "http:\/\/www.gunshine.net\/achievement\/info?achievementType=104857600",
    "type": "game.achievement",
    "title": "Meet The Challenge",
    "image": [{
        "url": "http:\/\/c459558.r58.cf2.rackcdn.com\/asset_0_10_9\/graphics\/achievement_icons\/achievement_unlocked_icon.png"
    }],
    "description": "Reach level 2",
    "site_name": "gunshine.net",
    "data": {
        "points": 10
    },
    "id": "10150273610694165",
    "updated_time": "2011-09-07T15:47:27+0000",
    "context": {
        "display_order": 0
    }
},
and so on....
```

As you can see the first 2 entries are incomplete, and I want to delete them, but according to the achievements documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/ the un-registering of an achievement requires a URL to be passed.

Is there a way to un-register an achievement without the achievement URL?

Trying to use the regular graph api delete mechanism results in an error message:

```
curl -X DELETE "https://graph.facebook.com/<incomplete_achievement_id>?access_token=<app_access_token>"
```

results in

```
{"error":{"type":"GraphMethodException","message":"Unsupported delete request."}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following
    curl -X DELETE "https://graph.facebook.com/AppId/achievements?access_token=...&achievement= full url"